# Finding Average of multiple samples

Tags: r

I am trying to find the average of "Answers" for a given ID (1,2,3). I have created a subset of data that includes only students not in the lab "N", and questions pertaining to lab "L" called "LRi". So I need to find a way to average of Answers for the subset data "LRi" for each ID number. I would also like to assign it as a numeric vector.

```
ID  StudentLab  QuestionLab Question    Answer
1   N   L   1   4
2   N   L   1   2
3   N   L   1   3
1   N   L   1   5
2   N   L   1   1
3   N   L   1   4
1   N   L   1   7
2   N   L   1   3
3   N   L   1   5
```

Results

```
ID  Answer
1   5.3
2   2
3   4
```

Comment: `aggregate(Answer~ID,data,mean)`

Answer (score 0):

Group entries by ID and summarise Answers by calculating the average.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Answer = mean(Answer))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#     ID Answer
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1     1   5.33
#2     2   2.00
#3     3   4.00
```